# Find a function with directional derivative zero such that:

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need to find a continuous function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $x_1,x_2,y \in \mathbb R$ such that:

1. $(x_1,y),(x_2,y) \in U$
2. $D_1f(P_o)=0$ for all $P_0 \in U$ (directional derivative for vector $e_1$).
3. $f(x_1,y) \neq f(x_2,y)$.

for $U=( (-2,2)\times (-1,1))$ \ $ \{ (0,y)\ |\ -1<y\leq 0 \} $

But how is that possible? the only examples I can find are functions without $x$, for example $f(x,y)=y^2$.

It seems that every function that its image is dependent on $x$ will not result in $D_1f=0$. And if I exclude $x$ from the image then $f(x_1,y) = f(x_2,y)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you double-check the way the domain is written? It doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: I double-checked, thats exactly what the question says. It really seems impossible to find one.

Comment: Oh sorry I just realized I actually just misread it. My bad. Yeah I agree that seems impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{U}$ be the open unit square with the negative $y$-axis removed (and the origin removed as well). Think of a piece of paper cut on the middle of one side until the centre and then make one flap go up and the other go down. More formally, consider the function $f:\mathrm{U} \to \mathbf{R}$ as follows: if $y > 0,$ then $f(x, y) = 0,$ else $f(x, y) = \mathrm{sign}(x) y.$ You can check this function satisfies $\partial_1 f = 0$ on $\mathrm{U}$ and yet, $f(-1, -0.5) = 0.5$ while $f(1, -0.5) = -0.5.$

Comment: But is it continuous?

Comment: Maybe you do not know the definition of continuity. If $x$ is not in the domain of $f,$ $f$ cannot be discontinuous at $x$ (even if your Calculus 101 teacher said otherwise).

Comment: Could you please explain? what do you mean $x$ isn't in the domain? why not?

Comment: You can only ever ask about continuity of a function on the domain of the function.

Comment: I get it, but why isn't x in the domain?

Comment: Check the definition of $\mathrm{U}$!

Comment: So you mean the function is continous everywhere except the negative y-axis, but since it's not in the domain, it is continous as requested? And thanks for the help!

Comment: The function is not even defined on the negative $y$-axis. Asking about continuity there is utterly nonsensical!